# MySQL group by with time diff

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

My Table Records like:

```
id         startFrom                   endOn               gateway   broadcast
1    2018-09-01T23:41:24:024  2018-09-01T23:45:24:028         A         X01
2    2018-09-01T23:41:24:025  2018-09-01T23:45:24:032         A         X01
3    2018-09-01T23:41:24:026  2018-09-01T23:45:24:028         B         X01
4    2018-09-01T23:41:24:030  2018-09-01T23:45:24:045         C         X01
5    2018-09-01T22:41:24:029  2018-09-01T23:41:24:784         B         X02
6    2018-09-01T23:41:24:025  2018-09-01T23:45:24:038         A         X01
```

If I wanna use single query to find first request time period in each gateway in specific broadcast. How to use MySQL to group it query?

Failed:

```
SELECT gateway, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, `startFrom`, `endOn`) AS `timeDiff` FROM Records WHERE broadcast = 'X01' GROUP BY gateway
```

And if I try to make a temp table like:

```
SELECT gateway, MIN(timeDiff)
FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, `startFrom`, `endOn`) AS `timeDiff`, gateway, broadcast FROM Records) t
WHERE broadcast = 'X01'
GROUP BY gateway;
```

It only get minimum time diff from records each gateway in this broadcast, but I have to query the "first record" (=> ORDER BY startFrom ASC) time diff.

Target output is:

```
gateway        startFrom                 endOn                 timeDiff
A       2018-09-01T23:41:24:024  2018-09-01T23:45:24:028         4000  
B       2018-09-01T23:41:24:026  2018-09-01T23:45:24:028         2000  
C       2018-09-01T23:41:24:030  2018-09-01T23:45:24:045         15000
```

Thanks for reading and helping

Comment: please share your expected output

Comment: If you have two or more `startFrom` values are the same (e.g. id 1,2) for a gateway, do you want both or a specific one?

Comment: specific one is ok

Comment: You input **endOn** and output **endOn** is not matching ? could you please explain why ?

Comment: Sorry, I correct the sample value

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the first for each gateway and broadcast, use this:

```
select gateway, broadcast, timeDiff from (
    SELECT gateway, broadcast, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, startFrom, endOn) AS timeDiff,
        row_number() over (partition by gateway, broadcast order by startfrom) as rn
    FROM Records ) q
where rn=1
```

EDIT:
Looking at the mySQL version 8 doc, syntax is different

```
select gateway, broadcast, timeDiff from (
    SELECT gateway, broadcast, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, startFrom, endOn) AS timeDiff,
        row_number() over w as rn
    FROM Records
    WINDOW w as (partition by gateway, broadcast order by startfrom)
) q
where rn=1
```

Comment: MySQL seem not having over partition by feature :'(

Comment: Apologies. But according to doc it does the same thing - I'll add

Comment: Sorry, but only MySQL 5.6 version can be used in this case

Comment: Oh well. Hopefully this answer can help the next person!

Answer (score 0):

select * from records;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
| id | startFrom           | endOn               | gateway | broadcast |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | 2018-09-17 05:23:53 | 2018-09-17 06:23:53 | A       | X01       |
|  2 | 2018-09-17 05:24:08 | 2018-09-17 06:24:08 | A       | X01       |
|  3 | 2018-09-17 05:24:25 | 2018-09-17 06:24:25 | B       | X01       |
|  4 | 2018-09-17 05:24:32 | 2018-09-17 06:24:32 | C       | X01       |
|  5 | 2018-09-17 05:24:42 | 2018-09-17 07:24:42 | B       | X02       |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------+

and Is this the query you are looking for ..

select gateway,startFrom,endOn,time_to_sec(timediff(endOn,startFrom)) as timeDiff from records group by gateway asc ;
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| gateway | startFrom           | endOn               | timeDiff |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| A       | 2018-09-17 05:23:53 | 2018-09-17 06:23:53 |     3600 |
| B       | 2018-09-17 05:24:25 | 2018-09-17 06:24:25 |     3600 |
| C       | 2018-09-17 05:24:32 | 2018-09-17 06:24:32 |     3600 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select gateway, min(startFrom),min(endOn), TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, min(startFrom), min(endOn)) AS `timeDiff` 
from records
where broadcast = 'X01' GROUP BY gateway
```

Comment: Because requests sent in parallel not serial, cannot use endOn for order in my cases

Comment: why you need endon in order by ?

Comment: It possible in this case:
|1 2018-09-17 05:23:53 2018-09-17 05:23:59|2 2018-09-17 05:23:54 2018-09-17 05:23:55|
so the startFrom order only is required

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below,

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS groupTime ;
CREATE TABLE groupTime (
id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
startFrom DATETIME(3),
endOn DATETIME(3),
gateway CHAR(1),
broadcast VARCHAR(8)
);

INSERT INTO groupTime (startFrom,endOn,gateway ,broadcast)
VALUES
('2018-09-01 23:41:24.024','2018-09-01 23:45:24.028','A','X01'),
('2018-09-01 23:41:24.025','2018-09-01 23:45:24.032','A','X01'),
('2018-09-01 23:41:24.026','2018-09-01 23:45:24.028','B','X01'),
('2018-09-01 23:41:24.030','2018-09-01 23:45:24.045','C','X01'),
('2018-09-01 23:41:24.029','2018-09-01 23:41:24.784','B','X02'),
('2018-09-01 23:41:24.025','2018-09-01 23:45:24.038','A','X01');


SELECT a.gateway, a.startfrom, a.endOn , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND , a.startfrom, a.endOn) FROM groupTime a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM groupTime WHERE broadcast='X01' GROUP BY gateway 
)AS b
ON a.id = b.id
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RVN92658)